# using Jquery to target divs taller than x

Tags: jquery

This is a part of a larger function.

```
setTimeout(function () {
            var moreOne = '<div class="more-1">View full size</div>'; //div to be appended 
            $(".figure img", $newElems).each(function() { //$newelems are things newly added to the DOM
                var $this = $(this);
                console.log( $this.height() );
            });

            if ($('.figure img').height() > 700) { // checking the height of the img within each $newElems
            $(".figure img", $newElems).fadeOut(); // goal is to append the div above, but testing with 'fadeOut' just now

            }



        }, 1000); // set a timeout to let them load properly
```

I'm checking the height of new images inside certain elements with the goal of prepending some content to them should they meet the condition of being more than 700px tall.

We can read the heights just fine, but what I can't work out is how to specifically interact with elements > 700px.

Currently this just fades out all the new elements, how can I only target the ones that are more than 700px?

Code is commented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `.each()` to iterate over all images. and use them using `$(this)` in handler:

```
 $(".figure img", $newElems).each(function() { 
  console.log( $(this).height() );
  if ($(this).height() > 700) { // checking the height of the img within each $newElems
        $(this).fadeOut(); // goal is to append the div above, but testing with 'fadeOut' just now
 }});
```

Comment: Why assign `var $this` to `$(this)` if you aren't going to use it every time?

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if I had HTML to work with but can you try this

```
setTimeout(function () {
    var moreOne = '<div class="more-1">View full size</div>'; //div to be appended 
    $(".figure img", $newElems).each(function() { //$newelems are things newly added to the DOM
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.height() > 700) {
            $this.fadeOut();
        }
    });
 }



    }, 1000); // set a timeout to let them load properly
```